# Create a criterion for Powershell to search and upload only screenshots to a video by the mask of the name of the parent video file

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm trying to create a search criterion in Powershell for all files ".jpg" by the mask of the name of the video file of the same name in the title.

When creating a screenshot for a video , the video player creates a file .jpg by the name of the parent video.

For example, it looks like this: "Any_name_file_video.mp4" and in the same folder there are several screenshots for this video of the form "Any_name_file_video.mp4.jpg_scrinshot-id"

In addition to the field with Screenshots, you also need the fields Name, Size, Duration

I'm trying this code

```
$videoExtensions = ".wmv", ".mkv", ".avi", ".mp4", ".mpeg4", ".flv"
$screenshotExtensions = ".jpg"
$Directory = "C:\Users\d3ck\Desktop\test"
$url_text = "https://example.com"
$data = @()
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force -Include $videoExtensions)) {
$screenshot = (Get-ChildItem -Path $file.DirectoryName -Recurse -Force -Include $screenshotExtensions | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -eq $file.BaseName})
if ($screenshot) {
$screenshotURL = $screenshot.FullName.Replace($Directory, $url_text).Replace("", "/")
} else {
$screenshotURL = ""
}
$url = $file.FullName.Replace($Directory, $url_text).Replace("", "/")
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace($file.DirectoryName)
$File = $Folder.ParseName($file.Name)
$Duration = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File, 27)
$data += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = $file.Name
    Size = "$([int]($file.length / 1mb)) MB"
    Duration = $Duration
    URL = $url
    ScreenshotURL = $screenshotURL
}
}
$data | Export-Csv -Path "./video-info.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force -Delimiter ","
```